# Why this c++ function is a struct

Tags: c++

I am learning C++, and a little confused with this C++ code using Trust Library. Here are my questions:

1. Why use keyword `struct`?
2. Why the function `is_word_start` has the colon part: :public thrust::binary_function"

   ```
   // determines whether the right character begins a new word
   struct is_word_start
       : public thrust::binary_function<const char&, const char&, bool>
   {
       __host__ __device__
       bool operator()(const char& left, const char& right) const
       {
           return is_alpha(right) && !is_alpha(left);
       }
   };
   ```

https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/word_count.cu

Comment: The function execution `operator()` can be called on an instance of this class, thus it can be called as a substitute of a simple function call.

Comment: Please continue learning C++. You're probably not quite ready for Stack Overflow at this point.

Comment: `is_word_start` is a [class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class), not a function.

Comment: The colon part is to indicate inheritance. Furthermore is_word_start is not a function, but a [function object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) class.

Answer (score 0):

1. struct means almost the same as class does except that by default all members of a struct are public, while in a class they're private. (You can specify access modifiers in a struct the same way you do in a class.)
2. The `: public` part means public inheritance. You should really read up on this and other inheritance types.

This class overloads a so-called call operator and thus an object of this class can be called as a function (with two arguments, in this particular case). Such objects are often called functors and are used widely in stl and everywhere else.

Comment: Also, the `public` is not necessary, because a `struct`'s base classes are `public` by default (you missed that in point 1).